# How to combine two postgres columns to single value (json object)

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query on my **food.list** table:

```
categories    | items
----------------------------
dairy         | ["milk", "cheese"]
fruit         | ["apples", "pears", "grapes"]
vegetables    | ["carrots"]
```

and return a **selected_foods** column with a single row. I want the row's value to be an object with a list of categories (keys) with an array of items (values).

```
selected_foods
------------------------------------
{ 
  dairy: ["milk", "cheese"], 
  fruit: ["apples", "pears", "grapes"], 
  vegetables: ["carrots"] 
}
```

So far, I've tried:

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(categories, items::json))::json 
AS selected_foods
FROM food.list
```

But this returns an array of objects, i.e.:

```
selected_foods
------------------------------------
[ 
  { dairy: ["milk", "cheese"] }, 
  { fruit: ["apples", "pears", "grapes"] }, 
  { vegetables: ["carrots"] }
]
```

I think I'm applying the *json_build_object* function too early...or maybe I need to unwrap them again after?

Any help would be awesome, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_object_agg`

```
SELECT json_object_agg( categories, items::json)  as selected_foods
     from list
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e53553993fdad6e70e07ae15eb814702)